# concat with comma seperated values if value is same in array objects

Tags: javascript

I have one object. I want to concat name in one object if the path is equal.

**For example:**

```html
[
 {
    name:'Gaurav',
    path:'./public/user'
 },
 {
    name:'Saurav',
    path:'./public/user'
 },
 {
   name:'Mohit',
   path:'./public/test'
 }

]
```

**desired output:**

```html
[
 {
    name:'Gaurav,Saurav',
    path:'./public/user'
 },
 {
   name:'Mohit',
   path:'./public/test'
 }
]
```

Comment: ok, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` to group the data based on path and then take `Object.values` of the object which would be your expected output.

```js
const 
 arr = [ { name:'Gaurav', path:'./public/user'}, {name:'Saurav',path:'./public/user'},{name:'Mohit',path:'./public/test'}];
 
 result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,{name, path})=>{
    a[path] ??= {path};
    a[path].name = (a[path].name || "").split(",").filter(Boolean).concat(name).join(",")
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var a=[
 {
    name:'Gaurav',
    path:'./public/user'
 },
 {
    name:'Saurav',
    path:'./public/user'
 },
 {
   name:'Mohit',
   path:'./public/test'
 }

]
var output = [];

a.forEach(function(item) {
  var temp= output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.path == item.path;
  });
  if (temp.length) {
    var tempIndx= output.indexOf(temp[0]);
    output[tempIndx].name = output[tempIndx].name+","+item.name;
  } else {
    if (typeof item.name == 'string')
    output.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I mean... it *works*... but good grief let's hope you never have to run it on a larger set of data...